# Controlling MOSFET driver's input levels

Tags: mosfet, voltage-divider, driver

I have a high-side MOSFET driver (MAX1614) that is used to power a device on and off. The /ON and /OFF pins of MAX1614 are connected to PCA9536 I2C-GPIO expander. The goal is to use a physical button connected between the ON and GND to power on the device and then use uC to power the device off when required.

MAX1614 contains weak pull-up current sources connected to /ON and /OFF pins internally. If I power PCA9536 via an external source, things work like a charm. However, when PCA9536 is left unpowered (as it should be when device is not working), it loads the ON and OFF pins in a way that they both are at 0.28V. This is read as low on both /ON and /OFF and the device does not power on when pulling /ON low via the push button.

At the moment I'm thinking about just using two resistive dividers (47K/10K, Vbatt=22V) to pull the /ON and /OFF to logic high. This seems to work and I can tolerate the power loss in the divider. Are there any smarter options (Resistor + Zener)?

Edit: Schematics, External button to GND is connected between Pins 4 and 5 in the right-most connector.
[image: High-side MOSFET control]

Comment: Please add a clear circuit diagram for your particular application. It would help us a lot to understand your _problem_

Comment: What about just a weak pull down resistor? Is that OK for your application?

Comment: I need /ON and /OFF to be logic high with nothing but the BATT connected. The weak pull-ups in MAX1614 are not strong enough and unpowered IO expander is pulling them down to undefined state.